# sidebar menu hide when click document for Blueprint Slide and Push Menus not working properly

Tags: jquery, menu, document, sidebar

I have implemented the sidebar menu from [Blueprint Sidebar Menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/), [DEMO](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/). By default , the menu does not hide when we click on document. To make the menu hide when click outside, I wrote :
    var showRightPush   = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
        menuRight           = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        body                = document.body;

```
    showRightPush.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
        classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
        //disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
    };
$(document).click(function(){
            if($(showRightPush).is(':visible')){
                $(menuRight).slideUp(4300);
            }
        });
```

My HTML is :

```
 <li class="">
                    <a href="#" class="show-right-button" id= "showRightPush"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                </li>

<nav class="sidebar-menu cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
    <h3 style="padding:12px 0; opacity:0.4">&nbsp;</h3>

    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <h3></h3>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info"></i>About Us</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Team</a>
    </div>

</nav>
```

But the menu automatically hides(time is increased to check) when click on show menu button. I think this is because the button is itself within the document. So how to prevent this ?

Comment: can you add your `HTML` markup and a demo with the problem that you get?

Comment: can you add a working `snippet` or `demo` in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your current problem? I can't seem to make it work even just to make it push to right

Answer (score 1):

I did this for me and it works. Just change a little bit your code and you're up and running.

```
var menuRight = document.getElementById('cbp-spmenu-s2');
var showRight = document.getElementById('showRight');
var body = document.body;
var menuOpen = false;

showRight.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle(menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
    setInterval(function() {menuOpen = true;}, 100);
    menuOpen = false;
};

body.onclick = function() {
    if (menuOpen) {
        classie.removeClass(menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
       menuOpen = false;
    }
};
```